# how to prevent user to access next page if the user is not logged in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is my main js file, where I want a condition that user must be logged in to access the welcome page, if user is not logged in then it must redirect it to login page by default, but in my code the form is submitting and redirecting to welcome page but does not implement desired result.

here is the main.js file

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"])

                    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
                        $routeProvider
                                .when("/",{
                                    templateUrl : "pages/login.html",
                                    controller : "loginController"
                                })
                                .when("/welcome",{
                                    templateUrl: "pages/welcome.html",
                                    controller:"welcomeController"
                                })

                            })
                .controller("loginController", function($scope, $location, $rootScope){
                            $scope.login = function() {
                                var user = $scope.username;
                                var password = $scope.password;
                                /*var result = $scope.username + $scope.password;
                                console.log(result);*/
                                if (user == "admin" && password == 'admin'){
                                    $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
                                    $location.path('/welcome');
                                } else {
                                    alert("INVALID CREDENTIALS");
                                }
                            }
                    })

                .controller('welcomeController', function($scope){
                    $scope.message = "welcome here";
                })
                .controller('logoutController', function($scope,$location){
                      $scope.logOut = function(){
                          $location.path('/');
                      }
```

And here is my welcome.html

```
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias officia praesentium dolore alias, enim nostrum doloribus natus nisi itaque quos ullam. Tenetur aut fugit qui minus, cupiditate, rem est unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit facilis excepturi laboriosam voluptates in doloremque ad, impedit. Nam sunt similique vitae voluptatem fugit molestias, quod accusantium alias nulla dolores ad.</span>

<div class="logout">
    <h4><span style="float: right; color:red; cursor: pointer;" ng-click="logOut()">Logout?</span></h4>
</div>
```

and login.html here

```
Enter user name: <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="username"><br>
Enter Password: <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="login()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing your check in the wrong controller.
do like this:

```
 .when("/welcome",{
                   templateUrl: "pages/welcome.html",
                   controller:"welcomeController",
                   resolve: {
                        userLoggedIn: function($rootScope, $location){
                              if(!$rooteScope.loggedIn){
                                   $location.path('/');
                               } 
                        }
                     }
                   })
```

I think this is a better way to achieve what you want...`resolve` execute before your `welcome` become active...so, you avoid to load the `welcome` page and only then redirect if the user is not logged in

p.s.: (maybe is missing some semicolon in my code but you can handle this)

Comment: But there is one problem with ths approach, when I logout, then it rredirects me to login.html page which is okay, but then if I change the url like this --> http://localhost/login/#/welcome then again its taking me to welcome page, which is not correct, If I refresh the page on reaching login page after logging out then its not going to welcome.html , only if I refresh the page! I hope you got my Query!!

Comment: as you create `$rooteScope.loggedIn` only when login page loads, its possible that you don't have this variable accessing welcome page directly which could be the reason of this bug. Use `console.log($rooteScope.loggedIn)` to see which value this variable has and then check this also to redirect.

Comment: I have tried it , it is giving me unidentified value

Comment: I believe you mean `undefined` so...try to change your `if` statement to `if(!$rooteScope.loggedIn || $rooteScope.loggedIn === 'undefined')` . Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In your `welcomeController`, you need to check if the user is logged in or not.

Try following:

```
.controller('welcomeController', function($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    if (!$rootScope.loggedIn)
        $location.path('/');

    $scope.message = "welcome here";
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use routechange event

```
angular.module(...).config( ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {...}] ).run( function($rootScope, $location) {

// register listener to watch route changes
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
  if ( $rootScope.loggedUser == null ) {
      // not going to #login, we should redirect now
      $location.path( "/login" );

  }         
});
```

})

Comment: any route change will move it to login

Comment: You have to check with login variable is true or false then redirect it to login if it false  according to your variable
if ( !$rootScope.loggedIn ) {
      // not going to #login, we should redirect now
      $location.path( "/login" );

  }